# Is there a way to catch typos in string literals in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object with both staticly-known and (sometimes) dynamic properties.

I'm hoping to have TypeScript help catch typos. Obviously this is impossible for the properties added at runtime, but typos in string literals could theoretically be caught.

The approach I'm taking is to try to allow dynamic strings but disallow string literal types that are not in the blessed list ("foo" and "bar" in the example).

For example, something like this syntax could work (but it doesn't):

```
type Options = {
    foo?: boolean;
    bar?: boolean;
    [index: NotLiteral<string>]: boolean;
}

type NotLiteral<T> = string extends T ? never : T


const o: Options = {};
o["fooTypo"] = true; // I wish this didn't typeCheck
o[callApi()] = true; // should be OK


declare function callApi(): string;
```

That index types can only be `string` or `number` is probably surmountable (there's probably a workaround) but the deeper problem is that `string` extends string literal types, which doesn't really make sense.

```
const x: NotLiteral<"foo"> = "foo"; // type is "string", but should probably be "never"
```

The rules for 'extends' don't seem to match those for assignability here (why?):

```
const x: "foo" = callApi() // type error (good) even though "string" extends "foo"
```

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: How would you or TypeScript know that `"fooTypo"` is a typo of `"foo"` and not a correctly-spelled index property? Also it's unclear what you mean by `string extends string ? never : string`.

Comment: if we could type the index property as NotLiteral then it would *have* to be of type 'string' and not type 'foo'. This kind of thing (whether a string is a literal or not) can be detected for assignability apparently, but not for `extends` (see ^)

Comment: ...what? `NotLiteral<string>` is the same as `never`, it's not going to magically pick up each value you try to assign and re-evaluate the type.